# How to run the latest version of a program?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I'm quite new to the Linux world but very happy with my Linux Mint installation. One thing that confuses me is that I'm not sure how to update certain programs. For example, I installed Blender from the repository, but the version is very old (2.69). I have downloaded the newer version of Blender (2.74) but I have no idea how to install it so that when I open up Blender from the menu icon, it opens up the new version intead of the old. How should situations like this be handled in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For popular software you will usually find other users who provide ready to use packages for your distro.

Example: https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender

Anything you install should go through the package manager in any case, so you can keep track & get rid of its files in the future.

If you just unpack a binary tarball somewhere in your home, I guess you'll also have to create your own menu icon for it... installing it as a distro package (or making your own according to your distro's docs) is usually the better solution though.

Comment: I added the repository via sudo add-apt-repository and it was succesfull. However launchpad is still launching the old Blender version. How can I use the repository I just installed to install Blender?

Comment: @Antti Update the list of available packages and versions with `apt-get update` and either update all installed packages with `apt-get upgrade` or only update Blender with `apt-get install blender`.